# how to specify a codec in apache camel mina

Tags: dsl, apache-camel, codec, apache-mina

I'm trying to use the hl7codec in apache mina.  I can see how to do it using spring e.g.

```
beans:bean id="hl7codec" class="org.apache.camel.component.hl7.HL7MLLPCodec"
    beans:property name="charset" value="iso-8859-1"
 /beans:bean
```

but can't figure out how to do it using POJO / DSL i.e. my route is specified as

```
from("mina:tcp://0.0.0.0:21110?sync=true&amp;codec=#hl7codec")
  .to("file://test");
```

but this can't resolve the #hl7codec id.

Given an allergy to Spring, can anyone suggest an alternative way of specifying the codec or replicating the Spring dependency injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using Spring at all, you need to enlist the hl7codec in the Camel registry. In pure Java you can do this by

```
SimpleRegistry reg = new SimpleRegistry();
reg.put("hl7codec", new MyCodecObject());

CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(reg);
```

The Camel in Action book covers this in chapter 4, section 4.3.1

Comment: Thanks Claus, had found you already answering this same question in another forum.  It works.